# Android default button properties

Tags: android, button

See how there is a darker area inside this highlighted button - darker compared to the lighter area above and to the left?

[image: problematic button]
'

Altering the button's background property from its default setting affects both the lighter and darker zones. Unfortunately this gives an impression of the button being a larger size.

How do I just address the colour of the darker zone? Alternatively how do I get rid of the lighter zone?

Edit:

The project is an almost blank canvas. I've done nothing except create this button. The theme in use is *Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*

```
<Button
  android:text="Save"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Please add `xml` code

Comment: I think the lighter and darker zones are part of one drawable for default android buttons, so I wouldn't say there is an easy way of addressing either one separately. Have you tried defining custom drawables in `res/drawable`?